# Jquery not recognize on click function second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I really need help.
Here's what I'm trying to do: I wanna create 3 div elements which are flying from top to bottom of div (#lang_flying_objects) and when i click "the right one" (by Id), I need to create three more. When I create them I assign them all class "snowflakes". 
But I am only able to click on the first group and my onclick function recognize the right id, but when other group is created it won't trigger the onclick function. 
PLEASE HELP ME.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script>  
function fallingStuff() {
    var $snowflakes = $(),               
        createFallingStuff = function () {
                var $snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes" id="first"></div>');

                $snowflake.css({
                   'left': (Math.random() * ($('#lang_flying_objects').width()/3 -    offset))  + 'px',
                    'top': (-(20 + offset)) + 'px'
                });
                // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
                $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake);
                var $snowflake2 = $('<div class="snowflakes" id="second" ></div>');
                $snowflake2.css({
                    'left': (Math.random() * ($('#lang_flying_objects').width()/3 - offset) + $('#lang_flying_objects').width()/3) + 'px',
                    'top': (-(20 + offset)) + 'px'
                });
                // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
                $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake2);                   
                var $snowflake3 = $('<div class="snowflakes" id="third"></div>');
                $snowflake3.css({
                    'left': (Math.random() * ($('#lang_flying_objects').width()/3 - offset) + 2*$('#lang_flying_objects').width()/3) + 'px',
                   'top': (-(20 + offset)) + 'px'
                });
                // add this snowflake to the set of snowflakes
                $snowflakes = $snowflakes.add($snowflake3);               
            $('#falling_zone').prepend($snowflakes);
        },

        runFalling = function() {
            $snowflakes.each(function() {

                var singleAnimation = function($flake) {                       
                    $flake.animate({
                        top: "500px", 
                        opacity : "0"
                    }, 10000);
                };
                singleAnimation($(this));
            });
    };       
    createFallingStuff();
    runFalling();

}
fallingStuff();    
</script>
```

And here is my onclick function:

```
<script>
    $('.snowflakes').on('click', function() {   
          var idInputed = $(this).attr('id');    
          if(idInputed == "first") //for example
          {
              fallingStuff();
          }
       });          
</script>
```

Why it won't recognize the onclick function for second group of created divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the elements are created dynamically, you should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.snowflakes', function() {   
    var idInputed = $(this).attr('id');    
    if(idInputed == "first") {
        fallingStuff();
    }
});
```